# Problem in proving that the set of integers $n_k:k\geq1$ is not bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I found a question which went on like this:

> Consider a sequence $\{r_k\}_{k\geq1}$ of rational numbers in the
> interval $\left(0,1\right)$ which converges to an irrational number as
> $k\to\infty$. Suppose $r_k=\frac{m_k}{n_k} \forall k\geq1$ where $m_k$
> and $n_k$ are positive integers with no common divisors. Show that the
> set of integers $n_k:k\geq1$ is not bounded.

I tried to proceed by the method of contradiction. So, suppose that the set of integers is bounded. This means that $\exists l_1,l_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $l_1\leq n_k\leq l_2\: \forall k\geq1$. Thus, we have that for all $k\geq1$,
$$\frac{m_k}{l_2}\leq\frac{m_k}{n_k}\leq\frac{m_k}{l_1}\\
\implies\frac{m_k}{l_2}\leq r_k\leq\frac{m_k}{l_1}$$

Now applying $k\to\infty$ to the above inequality, we get that,
$$p_1\leq q\leq\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{m_k}{l_1}$$ where I have assumed that $r_k\to q$ as $k\to\infty$ and $\frac{m_k}{l_2}\to p_1$ as $k\to\infty$. Now $p_1$ is rational. But that's about as far as I can get, with no contradiction in sight. Can anyone give me some hints as to how I can proceed?

---

I came up with a bit more while writing this answer. It seems like $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{m_k}{l_1}$ also converges to some rational $p_2$. But then again, the final inequality that I get is
$$p_1\leq q\leq p_2$$

Hence, I hit a dead end again.

---

Just for info, this question came in the ISI MStat 2022 PSB question paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n_k$ is bounded, then because $\dfrac{m_k}{n_k} \in (0, 1)$ there are only finitely many possibilities for $r_k=\dfrac {m_k}{n_k}$.  That means there are only finitely many differences between the possible distinct fractions, each of which is strictly positive, so those differences are bounded away from $0$ (because any finite set of positive numbers is bounded away from $0$).  In other words, $\exists \varepsilon \gt 0$ such that $r_k \neq r_j \Rightarrow \vert r_k - r_j \vert \gt \varepsilon$.

Also, because there are only finitely many possibilities for $r_k$, some $r_k$ must repeat infinitely often.

Let $L$ be the sequence's limit.  Choose $M$ such that $n \gt M \Rightarrow \vert r_n - L \vert \lt \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$.  Since $r_k$ repeats infinitely often, for some $N \gt M, r_k=r_N$.  Thus, $\vert r_k - L \vert \lt \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

If $r_n \neq r_k$ for any $n \gt M$, we know from the first paragraph that $\vert r_n - r_k \vert \gt \varepsilon$, so the triangle inequality tells us $\vert r_n - L \vert \gt \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$.  But $n \gt M$, so by assumption $\vert r_n-L \vert \lt \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$.  This contradiction establishes that $n \gt M \Rightarrow r_n=r_k$.

But then the limit $L=r_k$ is a rational number, contrary to the assumption that the limit is irrational.  Thus, $n_k$ can't be bounded.